# Как спарсить сайт с аттенншеном?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Я пытаюсь спрасить сайт, при переходе на который выходит оповещение, об использовании куки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Сам сайт](https://reg.o-time.ru/start.php?event=21117)

Если открыть сохранненый html страницы, то через некторое время она прогрузится, но кодировка будет сломана. Я пытался получить html обычным запросом

```
url = 'https://reg.o-time.ru/start.php?event=22191'

req = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

with open('index.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    file.write(req.text)
```

Я пытался сохранить без энкодинга, так же с utf-8, и utf-8-sig, кодировка везде сломана. Если использовать сразу принт без сохранения в файл ситуация та же.

Так же я пытался использовать selenium, и открыть в вебдрайвере, но там страница не прогружается вообще, остается на этом аттеншене(на скриншоте как раз эта ситуация) и необходимо вручную нажать ок. Еще я пытался скачать куки и открыть страницу сразу с ними, но в этом случае, браузер просто закрывался, и выдавалась ошибка:

> Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text :

Текст тот же что и на скрине.

Код с использованием куки:

```
try:
    # pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open('true_cookies', 'wb'))
    driver.get('https://reg.o-time.ru/start.php?event=22191')
    time.sleep(5)
    for cookie in pickle.load(open('true_cookies', 'rb')):
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(10)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: А что вам мешает зайти руками в браузер и нажать 'OK'? И после этого скапировать куки и спользовать их в дальнейшем в коде. при по следующих заходах на сайт эта окошко выскакивать не будет

Comment: У меня уже есть куки, проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь их использовать выходит ошибка. я использовал как куки полученные из pickle так и полученные вручную

Comment: Я так понимаю вы это сраницу будете парсить с помощью BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Да, с  другими способами я почти не знаком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup на автомате кодировку подберет

```
res = requests.get('https://reg.o-time.ru/start.php?event=22191').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!